# Accidentally entered password in to Git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

When pushing code to a remote, Git asked me to enter my GitHub credentials. At first, it asked for my username but I accidentally put my password in. This obviously appeared as plan text on the screen.

I'd like to know if that password is not stored in plain text on my machine and if so, how can I get rid of it?

Edit: this is Git Bash on Windows

Comment: I'm assming you're on Windows, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. I have edited the question to indicate this.

Answer (score 4):

Credentials are stored by the git-credentials helper configured for your system, configured under `cache.helper`.

The credential cache runs a daemon process which keeps your credentials in memory and hands them out on demand. They never touch disk. So if you kill your `git-credential-cache-daemon` process, it should throw all the passwords away. In turn, that should result in re-prompting you for your password if you continue to use this as the `cache.helper` option.

You can also turn off the git credential cache entirely, using `git config --global --unset credential.helper`.